# CKEDITOR - Cannot call "getSelection" of undefined

Tags: ajax, ckeditor

I'm trying to add CKEDITOR 4.2 (test with Chrome 29 and Firefox 23) on my site, `ckeditor.js` is loaded in the `head` section, the textarea is loaded in ajax, and then is replaced with :

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
```

But after that I can't write in the text field, and when I click on any button, an error appears `Cannot call method 'getSelection' of undefined`

```
CKEDITOR.dom.selection = function (a) {
    var b = a instanceof CKEDITOR.dom.element;
    this.document = a instanceof CKEDITOR.dom.document ? a : a.getDocument();
    this.root = a = b ? a : this.document.getBody();
    this.isLocked = 0;
    this._ = {
        cache: {}
    };
    b = o ? this.document.$.selection : this.document.getWindow().$.getSelection(); // Error
    // ...
}
```

It's working on an empty page and without ajax but not on the site, may it be a conflict with other script ?

Any idea ?

Comment: Could you create a sample on which this error will be reproducible? And please write which CKEditor version do you use and on which browser do you test this.

Comment: I think I can't, I already used CKEDITOR but I never get this error. I added the version in the post

Comment: Problem solved by delaying .replace(). Not the better solution but it's working

Comment: I am also facing the same error with angular 4 version and when I come back from another page using back button